# How to work with GridView in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**I am using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager**

I need to build a simple `Matching game` in android. Here is My `Model` class:

```
public class Model{
 private String name;
 private String SchoolName;
 .....
 // Getter and Setter methods
 ....
}
```

I am using `GridView` to show data and it's working fine but I want to put following constraint in populating `GridView`:

- Load Name in First Column
- Load SchoolName in Second Column

Currently It's loading in random order:

```
Name1                 |  Name 2
SchoolName 1          | Name 3
Name 3                | SchoolName 2
```

How can I do that? What is the good approach to do it?

Comment: Put your data in alternating order?

Comment: better to use ListView with custom adapter.

Comment: Use same view for both row with match to width having two textview for half half screen.

Comment: @Bhargav That means `GridView` always load data into sequential way? First column then second column in same row?

Comment: yes gridview doesn't load data randomly

Comment: @PankajKumar I didn't get you can you please give some hint pr Pseudo code?

Comment: but the best way to make sure is to use 2 list views in a horizontal linear layout with 0.5 layout weight i.e display 2 list views side by side

Comment: I don't understand. If you can create custom listview then why to use two different listviews. You can create object containing two strings one is name and other is school name.

Comment: ah yes sorry that was a stupid comment

Comment: Make sure use GridView with custom ArrayAdapter.

Comment: don't use gridview anymore if you are just beginning to use it, switch to RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager.

Comment: @HugoGresse Actually I am using RecyclerView with gridLayoutManager. Sorry for not mentioning in post

Answer (score 0):

Use a Custom Listview with this layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="HTTP://sachems.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ddd"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/name"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:elevation="1dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:background="#fff"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/school_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fff"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then display the name on the first textview and school name on the second textview

or you could do

```
position%2==0 {
 show name 
}
else {
 show school name
}
```

Comment: or if you have to use a gridview use column count as 1. and do the same thing

Comment: I think in second approach a lot of data will be missed out. For example: You will always pass an object to ListView or GridView or even in a RecyclerView.  First object : Check the position (position is 0) load Name then with second Object (Position is 1) load School name. So here We missed out `object[0].Schoolname` and `Object[1].name`

What say?

Comment: if you are using the second approach(which i am against) your listview size becomes 2xdatasource size.  what is wrong with the first approach?

Comment: Can I use CustomListView with RecyclerView?

Comment: if you are using recycler view. just change the layout to the one that one i have given. you dont need another listview.

Comment: I got it but with the above approach unfortunately I cannot make a Matching game. In `AdapterClass.onBindViewHolder` I will have to do 
`holder.textView.setText(object[position].getName);`
`holder.textView.setText(object[position].getSchoolname);`
That means right column will have exact answer on LeftColumn (Always).

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Take two arrays one for name and other for school name and set those using position attribute.

Something like:

```
private int[] names = {
      //names here
    };

private int[] schoolnames = {

        //school names here
    };
```

Then in adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if(position == x){
                //add name
            }
             else{
                //add school name
                   }

            return view;
        }
```

Comment: you should use `position % 2 == 0` in the condition right?

Comment: @Vinay This will work but I need to create two extra arrays. That is fine also but what about when I do have millions of data?

Comment: @Bhargav yes using position%2==0 we can do it.

Comment: @Amit: yes,it might be an issue for large data.When you have such big data it would be difficult even with one array